# Deserialize Json to Object in a constructor

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, serialization

I have an Object representing an entity and I would like to have a constructor with a JSON string as parameter representing the Object instead of having a JsonUtils (or whatever) to desearialize.
Example:

```
Imports System.Web.Script

Public Class Person

Public Property Age As Integer
Public Property Children As Integer
Public Property Married As Boolean

Public Sub New()
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal sJson as String)
        Dim serializer As New Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
        Me = serializer.Deserialize(Of Person)(sJson)
End Sub

End Class
```

Of course I can't set Me because compiler throws an error "'Me' no puede ser el destino de una asignación" ("'Me' can not be the target of an assignment", sorry but my VS2005 is in spanish).

How can I achieve this?
Is this approach the right way?

Enviroment: Visual Studio 2005, .net Framework 2.0 (not possible to update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing is simply to let the serializer create the new object:

```
 Dim p As Person = serializer.Deserialize(Of Person)(sJson)
```

To keep the deserializtion code in the class, you could use a shared method to create the new object:

```
Public Shared Function FromJson(ByVal sJson As String) As Person
    Dim serializer As New Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
    Return serializer.Deserialize(Of Person)(sJson)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim p As Person = Person.FromJson(sJson)
```

It is not all that different from the syntax for self-deserialization:

```
Dim p As Person = New Person(sJson)
```

Finally, you could copy each property from a deserialized temp var to `Me.Age` etc.  But whether property by property or thru Reflection, this seems needlessly complex for what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set `Me` directly, but you can use reflection to access every property and update each one from the json object. Example:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal sJson as String)    
    Dim sourceObject = serializer.Deserialize(Of Person)(sJson)
    For Each prop As PropertyInfo In Me.GetType().GetProperties()
        prop.SetValue(Me, prop.GetValue(sourceObject, Nothing), Nothing)
    Next
End Sub
```

This should at least start you off. You can do various error checks and set binding flags if you want to exclude some properties.

Comment: which is the purpose of "sourceObject" var? It is only initialized but not used

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to replace it. I'll edit it now. I did `prop.GetValue(Me, Nothing)` because I didn't actually deserialise anything